# MySQL Update Multiple Rows in one table

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
| ProductID | Description   | CostPerItem | NumberOfItemsOnHand |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 11        | Bike          |         150 |                 200 |
| 12        | Socks         |           2 |                 100 |
| 55        | Bicycle       |         150 |                 120 |
| 66        | Elbow pads    |          14 |                 120 |
| 78        | Knee Pads     |          12 |                  70 |
| 88        | Roller Blades |          75 |                  89 |
| 99        | Helmet        |          29 |                  30 |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+

+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName   | City        | PhoneNumber | AgentID |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| 10         | Barney    | Rubble     | Bedrock     |        -457 | NULL    |
| 12         | Monty     | Burns      | Springfield |         789 | NULL    |
| 13         | Wonder    | Woman      | Kypto       |        -346 | NULL    |
| 14         | Peter     | Griffens   | Providence  |       -3580 | NULL    |
| 15         | Fred      | Flintstone | Bedrock     |       -1568 | NULL    |
| 21         | Homer     | Simpson    | Springfield |       -8270 | NULL    |
| 31         | Sideshow  | Bob        | Springfield |       -4869 | NULL    |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+

+----------+-----------+------------+
| Quantity | ProductID | CustomerID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|       20 | 99        | 21         |
|       14 | 12        | 21         |
|       10 | 66        | 21         |
|        1 | 99        | 31         |
|        2 | 12        | 31         |
|        4 | 78        | 31         |
|        2 | 66        | 31         |
|        2 | 66        | 15         |
|        2 | 78        | 15         |
|       19 | 66        | 14         |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

I have 3 tables, one containing store products, one containing customer list and one table drawing relationship between the products bought and by which customer by holding the quantity, product ID and customer ID, which are both keys in their respective tables

I want to do write a statement where I can update the value of NumberOfItemsOnHand in the product table to 20 for each product thats been bought by "Sideshow" (first name in the customer table)

I tried to use write the statement:

```
UPDATE Product x
   SET x.NumberOfItemsOnHand = 20 
 WHERE x.ProductID = 
    (SELECT ProductID from BoughtBy WHERE BoughtBy.CustomerID = 
       (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customer WHERE FirstName = "Sideshow")
    );
```

I get an error saying "Subquery returns more than 1 row" and I have no idea on how to do it another way

Answer (score 1):

- You can approach this problem using `Inner Join` more efficiently instead.
- Join all the tables using their appropriate relationships and consider only those rows where `customer.FirstName = "Sideshow"`, and update the corresponding product's `NumberOfItemsOnHand` value.

Try the following query instead:

```
UPDATE Product AS p
JOIN BoughtBy AS b 
  ON b.ProductId = p.productID 
JOIN Customer AS c 
  ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND 
     c.FirstName = "Sideshow"
SET p.NumberOfItemsOnHand = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
UPDATE Product x
   SET x.NumberOfItemsOnHand = 20 
 WHERE x.ProductID IN 
    (SELECT ProductID from BoughtBy WHERE BoughtBy.CustomerID IN
       (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customer WHERE FirstName = "Sideshow")
    );
```